# What is right “didn’t have to” or “could”

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

There is question I tried to solve it but I couldn’t. The question says

> She (mustn’t) go by bus. She could take a tram or a train , too.

I should replace the word between ( ) with correct answer

My answer was “didn’t have to”

Is my answer right? And what is right answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, asking if something is right or wrong, or asking for something to be improved or corrected is off-topic here.

Comment: Should you replace the word (mustn't) with another word or phrase *with the same meaning*? Or do you have to replace to word (mustn't) with a phrase with a different meaning, so that the whole sentence is natural.

Answer (score 2):

*Doesn't have to* is very much **not** the same as *mustn't*.

*Mustn't* is a prohibition. *Doesn't have to* is the absence of compulsion_.

The original sentence with "mustn't" reads very oddly, because the "could" in the second half makes it sound as if "didn't have to" was intended, not "mustn't".

(I don't know what your native language is, but this is often a problem for German speakers, because *muss nicht* means "doesn't have to", while "mustn't" corresponds to *darf nicht*).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem comes from the fact that "mustn't" implies prohibition, whereas the "could" that follows implies possibility.